# How can I quickly dig out 3 chunks for my basement in FTB Infinity Evolved?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm expanding my 1 chunk house to a 4 chunks house.
I need to excavate an 3 chunk hole for my 3 floors basement (4 chunks total less 1 chunk already built).

My first thought was using a filler from BuildCraft, but that is prohibited in the overworld on the server I'm playing. Same for turtles and the BuildCraft and Extra Utilities Quarrys.

I can use a Tinker's Construct hammer and excavator but that would be slow.

So, **how can I clean the area quickly for I build the basement?**

Comment: I'm nit familiarized with BCraft. But when I want to clean an area, I use a lot of stone shovels.

Comment: Tcon hammer if upgraded correctly is probably a good choice. You said 3 chunks but how deep?  Even clearing a full chunk I've used hammer as well as Ichor pick axes going down and it's actually faster than bcraft options imo. Also cheaper overall with powered hammer that you can charge or if you can material repair on crafting table (may be disabled or unavailable feature)

Comment: What is your current tech level ? Is the Extra Utilities ender quarry allowed ?

Comment: Also, do you need to dig all the way down to bedrock ?

Comment: @Yotus no i don't need dig all way down to bedrock. Also, i updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Draconic Staff of Power](http://ftbwiki.org/Draconic_Staff_of_Power) can mine 9x9x9 at a time.  It also can be used to void particular blocks.  Just make sure you turn it down when you bring it into your base.

Answer (score 2):

A Tinkers' construct hammer should be able to knock that out pretty quick. Also using a `/dev/null` to void the `Cobblestone` would help with any lag.

Answer (score 1):

If it's allowed, the fastest way to do that is to use a bunch of nukes. Then, you can build the walls back using extra utilities's builder wand.